# PHP Contact Forms not receiving emails but acknowledged

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I have several different forms in a website. I started with the AGENCY Bootstrap theme, and it came with one basic contact form. I have generated 4 other booking forms using the same approach, html file > JS file > php file to mail the form details. The form which the template came with works fine and I am receiving e-mails, but for the rest of the forms - the form is acknowledged, I get a "Message sent", and I never receive the e-mail (not even in spam).

Here is an example of one (booking) form:

**HTML File**

```
    <section id="contact-tour">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Day Tour Enquiry</h1>
        <!--<p class="item-intro text-muted">Click <a href="#book">HERE</a> for hiring conditions</p>-->
        <p>
            <i>Kindly fill this form to enquire and we will get back to you as soon as possible.
            This is not an official booking. Further details, pricing and confirmation will be sent via e-mail.
            </i>
        </p>

        <form name="enquireTour" id="bookTour">
            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Enter your name">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" id="surname" required data-validation-required-message="Enter your surname">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Enter your email address">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone (including area code)" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Enter your phone number">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="location">Tour Location:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" placeholder="Tour Location" id="location" required>
                            <option> </option>
                            <option>Gozo Day Tour</option>
                            <option>Malta Day Tour</option>
                        </select>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="numadults">Adults:</label>
                        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Adults" id="numadults" required data-validation-required-message="Enter a number">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="numchild">Children:</label>
                        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Children (under 12 years old)" id="numchild" required data-validation-required-message="Enter a number">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="datetime"> Date and Time: </label>
                        <div class='input-group date form_date' data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" id="datetime">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pickup">Pick-up Location: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick-up location" id="pickup" required data-validation-required-message="Enter your pick-up location preference">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dropoff">Drop-off Location: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Drop-off location" id="dropoff" required data-validation-required-message="Enter your drop-off location preference">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                <label for="comments">Additional Comments:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Comments. Please provide any preferred sightseeing spots you would like to visit, if any." id="comments"></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="success"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="js/tour-inquiry.js"></script>
```

**tour-inquiry.js**

```
$(function() {    
    $("#enquireTour input,#enquireTour textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var surname = $("input#surname").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var loc = $("input#location").val();
            var total_adults = $("input#numadults").val();
            var total_child = $("input#numchild").val();
            var date = $("input#datetime").val();
            var pu_loc = $("input#pickup").val();
            var do_loc = $("input#dropoff").val();
            var comments = $("textarea#comments").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/tour_enquiry.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    surname: surname,
                    email: email,
                    phone: phone,
                    loc: loc,
                    total_adults: total_adults,
                    total_child: total_child,
                    date: date,
                    age: age,
                    pu_loc: pu_loc,
                    do_loc: do_loc,
                    addcomments: comments
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Thank you for your enquiry. We hope you to see you soon. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#enquireTour').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + name + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#enquireTour').trigger("reset");
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

**tour-enquiry.php**

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])                  ||
   empty($_POST['surname'])               ||
   empty($_POST['email'])                 ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])                 ||
   empty($_POST['loc'])                   ||
   empty($_POST['total_adults'])          ||
   empty($_POST['total_child'])           ||
   empty($_POST['date'])                  ||
   empty($_POST['pu_loc'])                ||
   empty($_POST['do_loc'])                ||
   empty($_POST['comments'])              ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$surname = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$loc = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['loc']));
$total_adults = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['total_adults']));
$total_child = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['total_child']));
$date = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']));
$pu_loc = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pu_loc']));
$do_loc = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['do_loc']));
$additionalcomments = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comments']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'correct@email-here.com';
$email_subject = "(Website) Tour Inquiry: $name $surname";
$email_body = "You have received a new Message.\n\n".
               "Here are the details:\n\n
               Name: $name\n\n
               Surname: $surname\n\n
               Email: $email_address\n\n
               Phone: $phone\n\n
               \n\n
               Date: $date\n\n
               Tour Location: $loc\n\n
               Number of Adults: $total_adults \n\n
               Number of Children: $total_child \n\n
               Pick-up Location: $pu_loc \n\n
               Drop-off Location: $do_loc \n\n
               \n\n
               Additional Comments:\n$additionalcomments";
$headers = "From: noreply@domain.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Comment: Once use same hosting email id in $header From field. Like if you domain is xyz.com then use like admin@xyz.com.  Actually once I stuck a problem that code was fine but mail was not sending.  Finally ask to website hosting and the suggest it.

Comment: That's how it is, I changed it for the purpose of the question. The file that is working is generic "noreply@yourdomain.com". This other file is "noreply@domain.com". I still don't understand the issue. Both e-mails are non-existent

Comment: Your form fields miss the name attribute. Fix it and you will see the magic

Comment: @LelioFaieta where exactly please?

Comment: I’ve checked name and surname input fields for example. You miss the name attribute that is what is required to send the value to the new page. The id is optional and. It required for form submission

Comment: @LelioFaieta I am unsure that this is the problem, as the working form uses id and not name and the e-mails are still being sent as expected.